# How do I access a Minecraft server running on my PC on the same PC?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, server-administration, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I have installed Minecraft Windows 10 Edition Beta v0.13.0 on my Windows 10-based PC. I am also running a MinePocket v1.6dev-51 (support v0.13.0) server on the same PC on port 19132 [edit: I managed to disable the built-in multiplayer functionality].

How can I access my own server on this same computer? I have tried `localhost`, `0.0.0.0` and `127.0.0.1` but this gives me a "Server is Full" error. I have looked through the [server.properties](http://pastebin.com/Jf5Q6Pyr) and the [preferences.yml](http://pastebin.com/Xwhq1RbM) files but they seem to point to nothing. I have also looked through the [logs](http://pastebin.com/7W6tBZ9q), but they lead to a dead end as well.

I have also tried white-listing myself and putting my Xbox Live gamertag in the whitelist file but it still says the same thing.

Comment: how many players are allowed on your server?

Comment: 9999 players in server.properties

Comment: Is that the default? maybe you can try something more reasonable like 2 for instance. I suggest trying your actual lan ip instead of the loopback address, I doubt this will work since it seems you are finding the server but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Are there any server log entries when you connect?  Do they say the same thing as the client?

Comment: @Aequitas I did try the default 20 people. It didn't work.

Comment: First off, have you hosted a working server before? and if you run cmd and type "ipconfig" what is your IPv4 address?

Comment: Yes I have. I do not want to reveal my internal IP for my computer which doesn't change due to me pegging the MAC address to this IP.

Comment: I have also port forwarded Java Minecraft before and had friends successfully connect. I run DDNS.

Comment: what mods are you running?

Comment: No plugins yet.

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per concisehornet80's answer (after resolving a duplicate chain)

Answer (score -2):

Try doing `127.0.0.1:62929`, that ought to work.

Comment: You do know I'm not using the Java version of Minecraft right?